# Heaps permutation algorithm done the opposite way....?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I was trying to use Heaps algorithm the opposite way by fixing elements at the beginning of array instead of last. But Im not able to get the results. Although I understood the theory part of this algorithm, it is confusing when I am trying to implement it. Im mainly confused about the swap statements inside the if condition. (please check comment). It would be helpful if someone can tell what the problem is. Thanks for your time.

```
function permute(string){ 
  var str = string.split(""), strbrr = [];

function swap(strbrr,index1,index2) {
  var temp = strbrr[index1];
             strbrr[index1] = strbrr[index2];
             strbrr[index2] = temp;
}

function permuteHelper(strarr, curr, end) {
  if (curr == end)
    console.log(strarr);
  else{            
    var fixed  = strarr[curr];
    for(i=curr; i<=end; i++) {     
      permuteHelper(strarr,curr+1,end);
      (end+1)%2 ? swap(strarr,end,curr) : swap(strarr,i,end);    //This is the most confusing part for me. What is the code here?
    }
  }  
}

permuteHelper(str,0,str.length-1);

}

var string1 = "ABCD";

permute(string1);
```

Comment: What does "please check comment" means? If you plan on elaborating your questions to add context and sample, please do so in your question instead of through the comments.

Comment: What he means actually is the comment part inside the code.

Comment: What is your expected output, given the string ABCD?

Comment: I mean what do you return. I don't see any return statements.

Comment: What I wanted to do was print all permutations, which Im trying to do by the console.log statement inside the if statement in permuteHelper. Pardon my coding skills..Im just a newbie. :)

Comment: `(end+1)%2 ? swap(strarr,end,curr) : swap(strarr,i,end);` This is just ternary operator. Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The code says, if (end+1) is not divisible by 2 then swap swap(strarr,end,curr) otherwise swap(strarr,i,end).